# Entity framework - select top

Tags: entity-framework, select

I have following data as sample in my tables
[image]

and I would like to write in Entity framework syntax query to archive the following SQL syntax

```
SELECT a.* FROM tblDocMaps a inner join tblDoc b
on a.CURRENTDOCID = b.CURRENTDOCID
where b.FORMONTH IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 aa.FORMONTH
        FROM tblDoc aa inner join tblDocMaps bb
        on aa.CURRENTDOCID = bb.CURRENTDOCID
        WHERE (aa.FORMONTH < GETDATE())
        AND (bb.INSTID=50)
        ORDER BY aa.FORMONTH DESC
    )
and a.INSTID=50
```

How could I write it to get result as I want? I would like to retrieve all record of the last 2 month from tblDocMaps where the  date defined in tblDoc.

Comment: if you are trying to use Entity Framework like you use SQL, you are missing the majority of the reason it exists.  An Entity Framework query should be much more organic, based on your c# entity classes, not on the way they are stored in the database.  If you list your entity classes, we should be able to help you build a query to do what you need.

Comment: tblDocMaps, and tblDoc was mapping by Entity Framework to an object call DocMaps and  Doc respectively.My query is trying to get list of DocMaps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteredMaps = tblDocMaps.Where(map => INSTID == 50);

filteredMaps.Where(map => filteredMaps.Where(map => map.tblDoc.FORMONTH < DateTime.Now)
                                      .Select(map => map.tblDoc.FORMONTH)
                                      .Distinct()
                                      .OrderByDescending()
                                      .Take(2)
                                      .Contains(map.tblDoc.FORMONTH));
```